# DirectX компиляция g++

Tags: g++, c++

Возможно ли компилировать программы, написанные на С++ под Windows с использованием DirectX, c компилятором g++?

Мне не нужна кросс-компиляция. У меня написана программа на С++ с использованием directx. На VC++ 2010 компилится и прекрасно работает. Но эта среда разработки довольно дорогая. Я хочу скомпилить эту программу c бесплатным компилятором mingw или ему подобным, чтобы не было ограничений в дальнейшем использовании этой программы. Если кто сталкивался, может, подскажете, что и как и с чем тут можно столкнуться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы собрать проект Visual C++ без Visual Studio, есть такие бесплатные варианты.

1. Windows SDK, который содержит заголовки, библиотеки, компиляторы, линковщики и т.п.
2. Visual C++ Express, если конечный продукт используется для личных или некоммерческих целей.

[Пакет Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/bb980924):

> Пакет SDK, выпущенный в феврале 2008 года, включает документацию, образцы, файлы заголовков, библиотеки и средства (включая компиляторы VS 2008 C++) для разработки приложений для Windows.

Вам нужно будет загрузить SDK с сайта Microsoft и заглянуть в примеры, которые включены в поставку. В целом проекты Visual Studio собираются в SDK, хотя может потребовать некоторая переделка.

Comment: Конечный продукт используется для коммерческих целей - 2 отпадает. Можно подробнее про win sdk и хотя бы вкратце с чего начать.

Answer (score 1):

Собствено g++ - врядли, но вот его портом под windows - mingw - вполне может быть.

Comment: Да, mingw поддерживает кросс-компиляцию DirectX на Linux под Windows.